# Blender Downloads and the information required to

Tags: installation

Where can I download a copy of the 'free' (and I use that word loosely in relation to Blender) Blender program without having to give my inside leg measurements, or signing up for a daily collection of spam emails? I don't want the world and everyone else to help me with a few 3d models that I want to use myself. I don't want to receive a 'you may be interested in this...' offer of add-ons or plans for a house, of horse. I just want the program because Daz3D says that I 'HAVE' to use this program. I even have to give my email address so that I can read any answers to this question, presumably because I'm too stupid to re-visit these pages knowing that someone has answered. Oh and my inside leg is 32".

Comment: Honestly, just out of interest, how did you try to download Blender? If I type "blender download" into any of my search engine, the [official download page](https://www.blender.org/download/) is always the first result. If this is difficult for some users, it should be improved, so sharing your story would help.

Comment: I'm also curious because you write "Daz3D says that I 'HAVE' to use this program". Daz3D is a commercial, standalone 3D software. Could it be that you signed up to some Daz3D newsletter? I would be very surprised if Daz3D *requires* you to use Blender. Just to be clear, Blender is not affiliated with Daz3D in any form.

Answer (score 4):

You can download Blender from the official website [www.blender.org](https://www.blender.org/). There's absolutely no sign-up required. Blender is truly *free* software, since it is open source and GPL licensed. More information about Blender and the Blender Foundation can be found on the [About page](https://www.blender.org/about/).

The following versions of Blender can be downloaded:

- [The current stable release](https://www.blender.org/download/)
- [Experimental daily builds of versions currently in development](https://builder.blender.org/download/)
- [All past releases of Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/)

Please check that your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running the current version of Blender. If your hardware is unsupported you may have to use an older version of Blender with lower requirements.